# How to query this date data?

Tags: sqlite

Column `LogTime` contains values like this : `08/12/2007 13:34:11`. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Log
WHERE LogTime <= '01/01/2011';
```

Table is defined like :

```
CREATE TABLE Log
(
LogTime DATE
);
```

Comment: Is the column LogTime a character field, or a date/time field?

Comment: Does WHERE logTime <= Date('01/01/2011') work?

Comment: When I run it like that it returns nothing and I have dates previous to 2011 in the table.

Comment: What does select max(logTime),min(logTime) from Log return?

Comment: Also, what does SELECT COUNT(*) from Log WHERE date(LogTime) <= Date('01/01/2011') return?

Comment: What does the min and max line return?   I am curious to see how the date is being stored in the server.

Comment: 12/31/2009 18:00:00|12/31/2009 18:00:00  My separator is set to a pipe.

Comment: Just to be double sure I spooled the entire table to file and eye balling the file I see a date with a value of 08/23/2007 08:00:00 so I'm not sure why the min is in 2009.

Comment: With the min returning the same thing as max, that explains why the query isn't working.   Now, need to determine why Min() doesn't treat the field as a date value.   What happens when you try to select distinct LogTimes, do you get 1 row back or a bunch of rows?

Comment: I get a lot of row back with all kind to dates and times.